# PC wont start after changing the case only

Tags: cpu, power-supply

Changed my case recently
Before the change it was working just fine.
CPU and CPU cooler were not removed and now I am facing the issue where the computer won’t start and when I press the power-on button the only the cpu cooler blinks the rgb lights , one very fast blink and thats it.
Any idea that could help solving the problem would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have something shorted, unplug everything you can unplug, all connections except power and switch, all cards, etc.  You will have just the MB and power switch cable and power plug plugged in. Then try. If works add 1 thing at a time.  If it still does the same thing you may have a mounting bolt touching a line under the MB.  Remove MB and check that all mounts are at a mounting hole on MB.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have screwed ALL the screws in. Those ground the mobo. I had the *exact* same situation happen to me and when I added the missing screw the machine booted.